# Jira setup on Azure VM

Tags: azure

I started with a Large VM running Win2008R2....I have JIRA setup and working from the localhost:8080 as well as NAME.cloudapp.net:8080 when on the VM.
I have set the endpoints on the VM for HTTP to 8080 and 8080.
How do I open the VM or subscription so outside browser can goto NAME.cloudapp.net:8080 and get the JIRA instance?

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to open port 8080 on the Windows Firewall on your VM.  You could use PowerShell or the Firewall App in Windows to make this change.

Answer (score 0):

On the management portal, click on the VM, then choose endpoints and add give a custom name and 8080 as the public port and 8080 as private port